# Share data between App and self-made Angular Library

Tags: angular

The architecture is like so:

```
<custom-header></custom-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<custom-sidebar></custom-sidebar>
```

Both `custom-header` and `custom-sidebar` are self-made library using [angular-library-starter](https://github.com/robisim74/angular-library-starter). For project-related reason I need to make these features libraries and not simple components.

Things are getting hard when managing data flow between the libraries and the app as all 3 are not living on the same project. Each one of them are separated folders and I need to compile each library with `npm run build` and use the newly created bundle.js in order to make `custom-*`works into the main app.

Main app is where the `LoginComponent` is. This `LoginComponent` includes the login form and login function that will authenticate users.

`custom-header`is where header template is. It should visually update as user is login or not. Here is `custom-header`:

```
<header >
  <user-details *ngIf='isLogin' ></user-details>
  <user-authentication *ngIf='!isLogin'></user-authentication>
</header>
```

The user details will show when user is log in. And authentication will show when user is not login.
However, I cannot manage to make login() function (located in main app) share data with `custom-header` and therefor cannot update isLogin.

I believe emitters are only for parent->child components. Shared services seemed like a good solution but as each 3 markups aren't living on the same environment, i couldn't figured out how to do so.

What I tried is this :

```
// header library
private ngDoCheck() {
  // Check is user is login
  if (localStorage.getItem("token") != null) {
    this.isLogin = true;
  }
}
```

It seems to work but I believe there is a better solution than ngDoCheck.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like you're missing common auth service here.

Comment: I do have auth service, it is located into main app. How can it helps?

Comment: You can use it in the library instead of accessing localStorage directly.